# What is the name and function of the symbol "$A^\smallfrown B$", where $A$ is an $m$-place sequence and $B$ is an $n$-place sequence?

Tags: logic, computer-science

I was wondering if someone might tell me the name and use of the symbol circled in red, the arc between A and B.

[image]

It comes from *Modal Logic: An Introduction to Its Syntax and Semantics* by Nino Cocchiarella and Max Freund.

I've checked Wikipedia and Math Vault (mathvault.ca), but to no avail. What is this and how is it read?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In that line it is being defined. It just produces the sequence that consists of concatenating the sequences $A$ and $B$. For example, if $A$ is the sequence $A_0=0$, $A_1=1$ and $B$ is the sequence $B_0=2$, $B_1=3$, $B_2=4$, then $A\smallfrown B$ is the sequence $(A\smallfrown B)_0=0, (A\smallfrown B)_1=1, (A\smallfrown B)_2=2,(A\smallfrown B)_3=3,(A\smallfrown B)_4=4$.

Comment: Some people call it a "frown."  This isn't standardized use; the author is just picking a symbol for "concatenate" and using it "locally."

Comment: Notation ${=}_{df}$ means this is a definition.  The item on the left is defined by the formula on the right.

Comment: If you're trying to identify a symbol, [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a good place to start. When drawing a bow like in your question, it comes up with `\frown` and `\smallfrown`, and indeed `A^\smallfrown B` seems very similar: $A^\smallfrown B$.

Comment: @NDB Thanks so much! Very helpful.

Comment: @B.Goddard I've never heard this term, but I like it!

Comment: @sTertooy Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

I think most of us, if asked for a name for the symbol, would call it ... 'the concatenation symbol'!

And if lecturing and reading out '$A^\cap B$' written on the board, I'd just say '$A$ concatenated with $B$' or perhaps more casually but making it clear which way round things go, '$A$ followed by $B$'.

As for what concatenation is, the quote gives you a neat technical definition ... and Wikipedia is your friend if you want some background!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: It should be $\frown$, not $\cap$.

Comment: I'd probably call the expression "$A$ join $B$."